# Chromatic index of an acyclic digraph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G=(V, E)$ be an acyclic digraph (DAG) with all in- and out-degrees at most $k$. Is it true that the edges of $G$ may be always colored properly in $2k$ colors?

In the discussion of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442170/4312) question it is proved (for $k=2$, but the proofs work verbatim for other values of $k$) that $G$ has $|E|/(2k)$ disjoint edges.

Comment: Isn't this just asking for the acyclic chromatic index of graphs with maximum degree $2k$?

Comment: @vidyarthi what is acyclic chromatic index?

Comment: By Vizing's theorem, any counterexample would have to have a vertex with both in-degree $k$ and out-degree $k$, and the underlying undirected graph would have to be a [class two graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Class2Graph.html). The usual suspects for class two graphs don't work here, but of course that doesn't prove much.

Comment: Did you try Galvin's approach for the more general list coloring problem, as described by Zeilberger at: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9506215 ?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam For bipartite graphs, the proof of Kőnig's theorem is certainly easier than Galvin's argument, so I'd be surprised if generalizing to list colorings makes life easier here.

Comment: @TimothyChow Choosability is sometimes easier to prove indeed, both the core method and the Alon-Tarsi polynomial methods are quite powerful. But I do not see immediately how to apply them here.

Comment: I still suspect that Vizing's theorem is a more promising direction. If you haven't consulted it already, I'd recommend looking at the book *Graph Edge Coloring* by Stiebitz et al. Your result may not be in there, but I think there's a good chance that the techniques of that book will apply.

Comment: @FedorPetrov see the definition and some classes for which a related conjecture is proved [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.01638)

Comment: @FedorPetrov But I think acyclic chromatic index should be a lower bound for the problem you ask

Comment: @vidyarthi I don't immediately see the relevance of the acyclic chromatic index. The use of the word "acyclic" looks like an accident to me. A key point about the acyclic DAG structure is that it places some severe restrictions on what kinds of (underlying) graphs can arise. For example, there must be at least one source and at least one sink, and a source or sink can have at most $k$ incident edges. If the result is true then these sorts of additional restrictions must come into play.

Comment: @TimothyChow Yes, I get it. But, I thought that acyclic chromatic index used rainbow coloring of the cycles, but after seeing the definitions now, I see that it has little relevance to the OP.

Comment: If we can find disjoint path $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ such that $G-(P_1\cup P_2\cup... \cup P_n)$ has all in-degree and out-degree at most $k-1$ then we can proof by induction, color $G-(P_1\cup P_2\cup...\cup P_n)$ by $2k-2$ colors and those paths by $2$ more colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution (obtained while discussing the question with my colleague András Sebő).

Consider the undirected graph $H$ obtained from $G$ as follows: the partite sets of $H$ are two copies $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $V(G)$, and for each arc $(u,v)$ in $G$ we add an edge in $H$ between the copy of $u$ in $V_1$ and the copy of $v$ in $V_2$.

The graph $H$ is bipartite and has maximum degree $k$. By [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) $H$ has a proper $k$-edge-coloring, that is a partition of its edges into $k$ matchings $M_1,\ldots,M_k$. The edges of $H$ are in bijection with the arcs of $G$, and if we consider the image of each matching $M_i$ in $G$ we obtain a subgraph of $G$ with in-degree and out-degree at most 1 (that is, a disjoint union of directed cycles and directed paths). As $G$ is acyclic, the image of each matching $M_i$ in $G$ is a union of paths, so the edges of $G$ can be partitioned into $k$ subgraphs, each being a union of paths. As a union of paths is 2-edge-colorable, $G$ has a partition of its edges into $k$ 2-edge-colorable subgraphs, and is therefore $2k$-edge-colorable, as desired.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed this clever answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, by "union of paths"  we mean "vertex-disjoint union of paths". And we also got from the proof  that "acyclic" can be replaced by the weaker condition "without odd directed cycle", i.e. :

*A digraph with all in- and out-degrees at most k, and  without directed cycle of odd size, has a 2k-edge-coloring.*

**Proof** : From the associated bipartite graph above we get a partition of the edges into graphs each of which is a disjoint union of *paths and even cycles*, therefore each of them can in turn be partitioned into two matchings, yielding a partition of the original graph into 2k matchings. Q.E.D.

The bound is of course best possible as two vertices and k edges in both direction show.